# When using decorations, how can I calculate with \pgfdecoratedpathlength?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I would like to draw a picture with tikz and use 'decorations' to show a single pulse on a line.

[image: Compiled Latex-output] Correct: A -- B

As you may see my code won't work for more than one segment ( A--C--B ).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ pulse after/.style={
% does not work with two segments:
            decorate,decoration={snake,pre length=#1, post length=(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength-(#1)-2mm),amplitude=5mm, segment length=3mm},thick}]
% doesn't work at all:
%           decorate,decoration={snake,pre length=#1, post length=(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-(#1)-(2mm)),amplitude=5mm, segment length=3mm},thick}] 

    \node(a){A} node(b) at (5,1) {B} node(c) at (2,-1) {C};

    \draw[->,pulse after=10mm] (a)--(b);
    \draw[->,pulse after=10mm] (a)--(c)--(b);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I tried to use `\pgfdecoratedpathlength` for multiple segments instead of `\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength` but it doesn't work at all. It simply displays no decoration:
[image: Result using <code>\pgfdecoratedpathlength</code> instead of <code>\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength</code>]

If you use e.g. `, post length=(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/2),` there are waves but of course not only one.  What is the problem with the use of `\pgfdecoratedpathlength`?

I want a single 'pulse' to be drawn after exactly 10 mm, nevertheless which way is taken and how many segments there are. Are there other ways to do this?

_

**Additonal description of the problem: (edit: 2013-10-04)**

I would like to draw a picture of the position of a pulse that takes different signal paths at the same time. If the pulse is on the way from `a` over `c` to `b` and for example 30 mm away from A, it is on the segment between C and B (and between A and B). I would like to draw this in even more complex examples by simply specifying the path and the distance from the starting point without calculating the distance of previous segments of the path.

Comment: If you exclude `decorate` from `pulse after` and then use the path as `\draw[->, pulse after=10mm] (a) decorate {--(c)} -- (b);` you’ll get one pulse from `a` to `c` and nothing less. That’s just a work-around around the multiple inputs …

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. This might work if the pulse is not further away than the distance between A and C. If it is, it'll get complicated.

Comment: One comment regarding my try for the post length calculation: I think the term `(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-(#1)-(2mm))` isn't evaluated. If you use `\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength` it will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to the fact that pre and post lengths work on the full decorated path. So as you can see the decoration continues before and after `(c)`. And in your `pgfpathdecoratedpathlength` case the 10mm plus the post length leaves the distance too little for the snake so switch to final state occurs.

I would propose a custom decoration that makes life slightly easier. Because if you zoom in to your adjusted snake you'll see the paths are not connected but rather chopped due to abrupt stopping of the continuous snake. You can simply draw a single pulse and continue with a line smoother.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{single pulse}{initial}{
\state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]
{%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10mm}{0mm}}%    
    \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
    \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
}
\state{final}{}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw](a){A} node[draw](b) at (5,1) {B} node[draw](c) at (2,-1) {C};
    \draw[->,thick,
         decoration={single pulse,amplitude=5mm,segment length=2mm},
         decorate] (a)--(c)--(b)--(a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The distance is harcoded and the pulse direction doesn't stay upright but those are certainly doable with less effort.

EDIT : For a single pulse you execute the pulse state once

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{single pulse}{initial}{
\state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength,next state=justdraw]
{%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10mm}{0mm}}%
\pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
\pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
}
\state{justdraw}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]
{%
    \pgflineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
}
\state{final}{}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw](a){A} node[draw](b) at (5,1) {B} node[draw](c) at (2,-1) {C};
    \draw[->,thick,
        decoration={single pulse,amplitude=5mm,segment length=2mm},
        decorate] (a)--(c)--(b)--(a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT 2: Only include the pulse in the correct distance no matter how many the path segments are along the way. I'm not sure what would happen when the distance corresponds to a node. I can modify the code such that if there is not enough space in the remaining path push the pulse to the next segment but that's a little cheating. So I'll leave it as it is which is also cheating :)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaredecoration{single pulse}{initial}{
\c@pgf@countd=0%
\pgfutil@tempdimb=0pt%
\state{initial}[
    width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength,
    persistent precomputation={%
  \ifnum\the\c@pgf@countd>0\relax%Nevermind
    \c@pgf@countd=2\relax%
  \else%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{%}
       \pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance+\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength
    }%
    \ifdim\pgfutil@tempdimb<\pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength\relax%
      \c@pgf@countd=0%
      \else%
      \c@pgf@countd=1\relax%
      \fi%
   \fi%
     }
]
{%
\ifnum\the\c@pgf@countd=1\relax%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{%}
    \pgfmetadecorationsegmentlength-\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance}{0mm}
  }%
  \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
  \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
\else%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
\fi%
}%
\state{final}{}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw](a){A} 
     node[draw](b) at (5,1) {B} 
     node[draw](c) at (2,-1){C} 
     node[draw](d) at (0,1) {D}
     node[draw](e) at (1,2) {E}
     node[draw](f) at (2,2) {F};
    \draw[->,thick,
        decoration={single pulse,amplitude=5mm,segment length=2mm,meta-segment length=16mm},
        decorate] (a)--(c)--(b);
        \draw[->,thick,
        decoration={single pulse,amplitude=5mm,segment length=2mm,meta-segment length=15mm},
        decorate] (a)--(b);
        \draw[->,thick,
        decoration={single pulse,amplitude=5mm,segment length=2mm,meta-segment length=15mm},
        decorate] (a)--(d)--(e)--(f)--(b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

We can also wrap the verbose settings inside a style with

```
\tikzset{
 pulse/.style args={#1w#2h#3o}{decoration={single pulse,amplitude=#2,segment length=#1,meta-segment length=#3},decorate}
}
```

then you can use

```
\draw[->,thick,pulse=3mm w 5mm h 30 mm o] (a)--(c)--(b);
```

for width, height and offset dimensions.

Comment: This solution creates a pulse after each node. I would like to display a single pulse on the whole path after a specific distance.

Comment: @dominik Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I'll update

Comment: @dominik See the update

Comment: Regarding my other try with `\pgfpathdecoratedpathlength`: I don't think there's too little distance left. See also my comment to the original question.

Comment: @dominik decoratedpathlength is from A to C to B all the way and yes there is an evaluation issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately it doesn't work if the `\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{30mm}{0mm}}` is further away from `(a)` than the distance between `a` and `c`.

Comment: @dominik Can you describe exactly what you need in the question? For that you are far better off with Qrrbrbbirlbel's comment if you want to place the decoration in the middle selecting the branch and only decorating it.

Comment: I added an additional description in the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10886/discussion-between-dominik-and-percusse)

Comment: Nice solution. As @percusse figured out in the chat: If the direction is the other way around, you may get a 'positive' pulse by adding the `mirror` option in the decoration list.